# Unable to set radio as checked and enclosing label as active using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have one set of radio buttons (greatly simplified from original HTML):

```
<form action="javascript:;" id="signup-form">
    <div id="first">
        <label class="custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="delivery-mode" value="normal">
        </label>
        <label class="custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="delivery-mode" value="scheduled">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click on a radio button in the first set I want the corresponding radio button in the second set to also be checked.

```
<div id="second">
    <label class="custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="delivery-mode" value="normal">
    </label>
    <label class="custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="delivery-mode" value="scheduled">
    </label>
</div>
```

I attempt to do this using this jQuery function:

```
$('#first').on('click', '.custom-radio', function() {
    var selector;
    if ($this.find('[value="scheduled"]').is(':checked')) {
        selector = '[value="scheduled"]';
    } else {
        selector = '[value="normal"]';
    }
    var radio = $('#second').find(selector);
    var cRadio = radio.parent();
    cRadio.click();
    cRadio.addClass('active');
    radio.prop('checked', true);
});

$('#second').on('click', '.custom-radio', function() {
    //console.log('hello');
    var value = $(this).find('input').val();
    console.log(value);
});
```

I know I am finding correctly the corresponding radio label in the second set of radio buttons because the click works correctly.

However adding the 'active' class to the label does not work nor does setting the checked attribute of the radio button. I was able to do other things like modify the value of the radio button or change the class to something else other than 'active'. But for some reason I can't do these two things to indicate the radio button was checked.

What am I doing wrong? Please help. :-)

Comment: If the name of all your radio buttons is the same, only one of the four buttons can be checked.

Comment: Thanks but the issue wasn't with the naming of the inputs. I over-simplified my HTML and forgot to put the first set of inputs within a form. I have since updated the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I am not able to boil down the problem that I am seeing to something reproducible for the stackoverflow community. Therefore I am going to mark this question as resolved. If I can reproduce in a simple manner then I'll repost.